# find all the hills and valley in a list

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing a function to find all the hills and valleys in a given list. For instance, [1,0,0,0,1] returns 3 and [0,1,0,1,0] returns 5. [0,2,2,1,1,0,0] returns 3. If a number (or consecutive numbers with same values) are bigger or smaller than both of its neighbors, it is considered as a hill or a valley.

Below is my code:

```
def hill_and_vally(s):
    if not s or len(s) < 2:
        return 0
    i = 0
    count = 0
    pre = None
    while i < len(s):
        if i == 0:
            while s[i] == s[i+1]:  # loop until value is different
                i += 1
            i += 1
            if i < len(s):       # check if it reaches the end 
                count += 1
                pre = s[i-1]     # track the previous value
        elif i == len(s) - 1:
            while s[i] == s[i-1]:  
                i -= 1
            i -= 1
            if i >= 0:
                count += 1
            break
        else:
            while s[i] == s[i+1]:
                i += 1
            i += 1
            if s[i] > s[i-1] and pre > s[i-1]:  # it is a valley
                count += 1
            elif s[i] < s[i-1] and pre < s[i-1]:  # it is a hill
                count += 1
            pre = s[i-1]
    return count
```

Can someone help me to improve the complexity to O(N). Or show me another way to do it with better complexity? Please show me some examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this 3? `[0,2,2,1,1,0,0]` isn't this `(0) (2,2) (1,1) (0,0)`  `4` ?

Comment: @SamerTufail `1` is not a local minima nor a local maxima.

Comment: 0: valley   22: hill    00: valley    11 is neither a hill nor a valley

Comment: @12345: I suggest, you add the explanation to the question by editing it. The whole question can't be understood without that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

- compute differences `d` between consecutive elements (remove `0`s from result)
- count the number of times the sign changes in `d`
- return 2 plus that count (because there is a hill and a valley even in a monotonically increasing sequence)

In code:

```
def hill_and_vally(s):
    d=[x1-x0 for x0,x1 in zip(s,s[1:]) if x1!=x0]
    return 2+sum(d0*d1<0 for d0,d1 in zip(d,d[1:]))
```

of course it can be implemented with `for` loops and indexes, but `zip` and list comprehensions is more pythonic.

`zip(s,s[1:])` is a common way to get pairs of adjacent elements in a list.

Tests:

```
>>> hill_and_vally([1,0,0,0,1])
3
>>> hill_and_vally([0,1,0,1,0])
5
>>> hill_and_vally([0,2,2,1,1,0,0])
3
```

Handling corner cases such as the reported `[1,1,1,1]` is left as an exercise  :-)

Comment: Great solution! Thank you.

Comment: It fails with all-equal input like `[1, 1, 1, 1]` and outputs `2` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 2):

I know that the question is quite old and already answered, but recently solved the same problem with just one linear scan:

```py
def solution(arr):
  prev = None
  curr = None
  total = 0

  for n in arr:
    if curr == None:
      curr = n
    else:
      if n != curr:
        if prev != None:
          if (prev < curr and n < curr) or (prev > curr and n > curr):
            total += 1
        else:
          prev = curr
          total += 1
        prev = curr
        curr = n

  if prev != curr:
    total += 1

  return total
```

It works well for all the inputs:

```py
print(solution([1]))                   # 1
print(solution([1,2]))                 # 2
print(solution([1,1,1]))               # 1
print(solution([1,2,1]))               # 3
print(solution([1,2,6]))               # 2
print(solution([1,2,3,4,4,3,4,4,5,6])) # 4
print(solution([-10,2,2,2,2]))         # 2

print(solution([1,0,0,0,1]))           # 3
print(solution([0,1,0,1,0]))           # 5
print(solution([0,2,2,1,1,0,0]))       # 3
```

What it does, it keeps track of previous downhill/uphill and increments `total` counter if another appropriate downhill/uphill is met.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome algorithm. Can I connect with you to discuss it.