# Find if valley exists in integer list

Tags: python, algorithm

> A list of integers is said to be a valley if it consists of a sequence of strictly decreasing values followed by a sequence of strictly increasing values. The decreasing and increasing sequences must be of length at least 2. The last value of the decreasing sequence is the first value of the increasing sequence.
>
> Write a Python function valley(l) that takes a list of integers and returns True if l is a valley and False otherwise.
>
> Here are some examples to show how your function should work.
>
> ```
> >>> valley([3,2,1,2,3])
> True
>
> >>> valley([3,2,1])
> False
>
> >>> valley([3,3,2,1,2])
> False
> ```

I have been sleepless for 2 days and the best i could write is this code

```
def valley(list):
    first =False
    second=False
    midway=0
    if(len(list)<2):
        return False
    else:
        for i in range(0,len(list)):
            if(list[i]<list[i+1]):
                first=True
                midway=i
                break
        for j in range(midway,len(list)-1):
            if(list[j]<list[j+1] and j+1==len(list)):
                Second=True
                break
            if(list[j]>=list[j+1]):
                second=False
                break
    if(first==True and second==True):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: What outputs **are** you getting? What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find all the hills and valley in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50638502/find-all-the-hills-and-valley-in-a-list)

Comment: There's no need for parentheses in `if (expr):` in Python.

Comment: Tip: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence

Comment: That wikipedia page was helpful. Let me work it out and get back to you.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Few days ago i was stuck trying to solve this Python puzzle.....but now it's all solved Thank you....and by the way some one just edited my question which is more confusing....not my doing....but anyway found my solution so thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems [saurav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238937/7089239) beat me to the punch, but if you'll allow for some NumPy magic:

```
import numpy as np


def valley(arr):
    diff = arr[:-1] - arr[1:]

    gt = np.where(diff > 0)[0]
    lt = np.where(diff < 0)[0]
    d = np.sum(diff == 0)

    if gt.size == 0 or lt.size == 0:
        # Doesn't have ascendings or decendings
        return False
    elif d > 0:
        # Has a flat
        return False
    elif gt[-1] > lt[0]:
        # Not strictly one descent into one ascent
        return False
    else:
        return True

a = np.array([3, 2, 1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([3, 3, 2, 1, 2])
c = np.array([3, 2, 1])
d = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])

print(valley(a), valley(b), valley(c), valley(d))
>>> True False False False
```

You can also use plain old Python builtins to do it:

```
def valley(arr):
    diff = [i1-i2 for i1, i2 in zip(arr, arr[1:])]

    gt = [i for i, item in enumerate(diff) if item > 0]
    lt = [i for i, item in enumerate(diff) if item < 0]
    d = sum([True for d in diff if d == 0])

    if len(gt) == 0 or len(lt) == 0:
        # Doesn't have ascendings or decendings
        return False
    elif d > 0:
        # Has a flat
        return False
    elif gt[-1] > lt[0]:
        # Not strictly one descent into one ascent
        return False
    else:
        return True

a = [3, 2, 1, 2, 3]
print(valley(a), ...)
>>> True False False False
```

Comment: Thanks Felix for the mention.

Answer (score 2):

The solution i found that also works if the numbers are not in perfect sequence and it is not necessary that the lowest value must be equal to 1, what i'm trying to say is if the list is suppose [14,12,10,5,3,6,7,32,41], here also a valley is formed, as the values are decreasing up to 3(lowest) and then it's again increasing. List's such as [4,3,2,1,2,3,4] is a perfect valley.

Solution:

```
def valley(lst):
if len(lst)<2:
    return False
else:
    p = lst.index(min(lst))
    for i in range (0,p):
        x = (lst[i] > lst[i+1])

    for q in range (p,len(lst)-1):
        y = (lst[q]< lst[q+1])

    return (x==y)
```

Don't forget to accept it if this solves the problem and is most helpful, thank you.

Comment: The solution was already given but still i gave you an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

The result of variable n in valley function, is the pairwise difference of the numbers in the input list, so if

```
input = [3,2,1,2,3]
n = [-1, -1, 1, 1]
```

Now the next variable h is, again pairwise difference of the n, so h will be

```
h = ['0', '2', '0']
```

So, every time you will have a valley, you just have to check the pattern "020". Use re module in python to do so,

```
import re
def valley(f):   
    n  = [j-i for i, j in zip(f[:-1], f[1:])]
    h = [str(j-i) for i, j in zip(n[:-1], n[1:])]
    result = "".join(h)
    m = re.search('020', result)
    if m:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Please let me know if its correct or not.

Comment: Can confirm with my examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52238959/7089239) as basic lists that this works.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I did not want to send a complete solution but I just wanted to solve and  for the first, and hopefully last, time I'm posting a solution for a task.

Here is my solution, of course there may be other solutions this is the first one my fingers typed.

```
def valley(heights):
    directions = []

    # Check input
    if not heights:
        return False

    # Traverse array and compare current height with previous one
    # if we are going down or up.
    pre = heights[0]
    for h in heights[1:]:
        if h > pre:
            # If we are going upward add 1
            directions.append(1)
        elif h < pre:
            # If we are going downward add -1
            directions.append(-1)
        pre = h

    # We have many -1s and 1s in out directions list.
    # However, if it is a valley then it should first down and up
    # which is [-1, 1]. Return the comparison result with [-1, 1]
    return set(directions) == set([-1, 1])
```

Comment: This solution incorrectly returns True for cases where there are flats and for cases where instead of a valley we have a peak.

Comment: @Felix yes you are right, but you know this solution is just for inspiration about how this task can be solved. But thank you!